# General SCII tips for a beginner?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting started with StarCraft II](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45356/getting-started-with-starcraft-ii)

I'm just getting into StarCraft 2 and I'm finding it really difficult to stay organized and on top of things. Does anyone have some basic advice for the complete beginner? Maybe a good build to start me off? I play Terran for the moment, as I'm still on the started edition.

As of now, I'm trying to follow Day[9]'s "Mental Checklist", which is essentially:

- Keep Minerals Low
- Watch Food Cap
- Train SCVs
- Train Units
- Build Buildings
- Repeat...

And my basic build order is something along the lines of:

- Supply
- Rax
- Gas
- Marine
- Orbital

So far, I've played two games against an Easy AI (TvT and TvP) on Normal speed, and won both, as well as a game against a more experienced friend of mine (TvZ), in which I did really well in the beginning, but due to the fact that I didn't realize he could stealth his units, I got squashed.

Comment: Vaguely dupe-ish, but not quite. See also: [1](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3741/what-race-would-be-better-for-a-beginner-in-starcraft-2) [2](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11760/where-can-i-find-a-good-starcraft-2-community-to-learn-how-to-play-the-game) [**3**](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2900/besides-practicing-what-are-some-great-ways-to-become-a-better-player)* [4](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7209/how-can-i-teach-my-less-skilled-friends-the-value-of-scouting-and-aggression)

Comment: [5](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6996/initial-starcraft-multiplayer-training) [6](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8964/stuck-in-starcraft-ii-improvement) [**7**](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45356/getting-started-with-starcraft-ii)* [**8**](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/918/what-are-the-popular-openings-builds-for-terran-in-starcraft-2)* (Asterisks denote particularly great related/dupe links. All three are must reads on the subject.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learn a standard opening, commonly called a build order, that forces you to expand early. This will put you out of your comfort zone but will improve your skill quickly as you learn to defend your bases against aggressive low-level play.

I recommend the [1 Barracks Fast Expand](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/1_Rax_FE) build from Liquipedia.

Definitely play on the fastest possible speed, essentially no one plays on anything but it.

Comment: I looked some examples of this up on youtube, looks like a good starting point. What would you recommend I do after Gas(1)/rax(2)?

Comment: At lower levels of play you're more likely going to see aggressive attacks that would be difficult to defend if you went for gas and tech quickly. Get the 2/3 Barracks up fast.